# Changing to template literals

Tags: ecmascript-6

How do I change this code:

```
var txt = "";
  txt += "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
  txt += "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
  txt += "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
  txt += "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
  txt += "<p>Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "</p>";
  txt += "<p>Browser Online: " + navigator.onLine + "</p>";
  txt += "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
  txt += "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
```

to template literals?
I tried but I'm doing something wrong.
By the way the editor here doesn't allow me to add more code, otherwise I could show you what I have tried so far.

Comment: Did you use backticks ` instead of double quotes " / single quotes ' ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also removed all + and " signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
var txt = `
  <p>Browser CodeName: ${navigator.appCodeName}</p>
  <p>Browser Name: ${navigator.appName}</p>
  <p>Browser Version: ${navigator.appVersion}</p>
  <p>Cookies Enabled: ${navigator.cookieEnabled}</p>
  <p>Browser Language: ${navigator.language}</p>
  <p>Browser Online: ${navigator.onLine}</p>
  <p>Platform: ${navigator.platform}</p>
  <p>User-agent header: ${navigator.userAgent}</p>
`;
```

Look at this to understand how it works :
[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thanks, I did the same. But it seems that it doesn't work in IE11. Please try to open this URL in IE11: https://jsbin.com/xogaqad/edit?js,output

Comment: Ok, look at the Browser compatibility at the bottom page of the link I gave you.
You'll see that IE11 is not compatible, you have to use a transpiler like babel.

https://babeljs.io/

Comment: Yes, damn it. IE11 doesn't support template literals. Thanks